# Will Intents started by AlarmManager retain its objects between runs?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I have an app that uses an AlarmManager to do a task regularly. From the Intent that is called by the AlarmManager I access the application to get access to shared data.

```
Application foo = getApplication();
```

I then use the foo object both for reading and writing data. Most of the lifecycle of this app is in a resting state with occasional wake ups.

According to the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is
>   broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application
>   if it is not already running.

But what happens to the instatiated foo object? (And all other objects in that is created by the Intent) Will that be the same as during the previous iteration or will it be a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foo` object, being an instance of the `Application` class, will remain in existence as long as

- the *process* in which this is app is running remains alive.
- the garbage collector does not mark & sweep through objects on your app heap.

When the process is killed, memory is reclaimed by the kernel and your `foo` object would vanish. If your app recedes into the background for a long time, then the `foo` object is no longer *in scope* and will be disposed of in the normal way by the garbage collector.

Every time the `AlarmManager` creates a new instance of your `Service`, a new process running your app is spawned (if the app is not already running) and the `Service` is run from within this process. The `foo` object remains in scope as long as the containing process is alive and it has a valid reference on the heap.

As a developer, you should always assume that between separate runs of your `Service`, either the process containing your app will be killed, **OR** the GC will mark & sweep through your app's heap. This is the most likely scenario and you have no control over it. So the answer to your question is that the `foo` object will probably be a new instance every time your `Service` runs.

For more, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Good answer. In other words, I should avoid keeping volatile data in the attributes of the foo object.

Comment: If your process is killed the Dalvik vm won't be running. That memory is cleaned up by the kernel. Android does teardown activities and issue memory warnings which you can respond to and release some of your objects, but you get none of this if your process is simply wiped by low memory killer.